# PHP Output also in Child theme, but different

Tags: php, functions, pages

I have a multilingual site setup: www.jeroenbrugman.com

The main dutch version uses Fluxus. On the artwork page I output a link using this from Functions.php

```
function prefix_term_name($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
  foreach ($terms as &$term) {
    $term->name = 'Terug naar '.$term->name;
  }
}
  return $terms;
```

And on the page itself I show it using this:

```
 <h3 class="widget-title">
                                <?php
  add_filter( 'get_the_terms','prefix_term_name',10,3);
  the_terms($post->ID, 'fluxus-project-type'); 
  remove_filter( 'get_the_terms','prefix_term_name',10,3); ?>
                                <a href="../"><?php the_terms($post->ID, 'fluxus-project-type'); ?></a></h3>
```

But, on my English page. I need to output the 'Terug naar' from the main theme function.php as: 'Back To'. but when I copy the code from main functions.php to my child theme's functions.php and change Terug naar to Back to the whole english site goes blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the function pluggable, that means, to support child themes, the functions in parent theme should use:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'function_name' )) {
    function function_name() {
        //Stuffs
    }
}
```

You should have seen a PHP Error message if you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

**EDIT:** The below code snippet if to answer your other question in comment.

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    global $post;

    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';

}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

Comment: So this   `if ( !function_exists( 'function_name' )) {
    function function_name() {
        function prefix_term_name($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
  foreach ($terms as &$term) {
    $term->name = 'Terug naar '.$term->name;
  }
}
  return $terms;
    }
}  `   Should be in my parent theme's functions.php. And I will be able to use the same code without your code in my child theme's functions.php?

Comment: I also tried this for the modify_read_more_link function. Making it pluggable in the function.php of my main theme. This didn't work tho.  `if ( !function_exists( 'modify_read_more_link' )) {   
  add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );   
function modify_read_more_link() {   
return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read more</a>';
}
}`  This was the code used with your plugging

Comment: Could you help me one more time?

Comment: @ginobrugman what happens when you add the code above? Is there any other function with name `modify_read_more_link` exists in parent theme?

Comment: I made it pluggable. Even put it above the prefix_term_name function mentioned earlier. None of this works. Also there are no other functions using modify_read_more_link

Comment: @ginobrugman You don't need to make it pluggable since there are no functions modifying the read more link. Simple returning of the new link will be sufficient. I have added a solution to my answer. Try it and let me know if that works.

Comment: Added your code to my child themes functions.php, No luck tho :(

Comment: @ginobrugman what exactly you are getting when you put that code? Blank output? wrong link? What?

Comment: nothing, the page shows normally. Except the read more link on my english blog page doesnt change.

Comment: I've searched my template thoroughly but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed!

Had to wrap my function with

```
if ( !function_exists( 'function_name' )) {
    function function_name() {
        //Stuffs
    }
}
```

Perfect!